# How many values does $\sqrt{\sqrt{i}}$ have?

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram says, there are only two roots, but $\sqrt{i}$ already gives two roots. So if we express them in Cartesian form we can take square roots of them separately and end up with four roots.

$$\sqrt{i}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$
But also
$$\sqrt{i}=e^{\frac{-3i\pi}{4}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$
Then take square roots of each of those and you end up with 
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{i}}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{8}},e^{\frac{5i\pi}{4}},e^{\frac{-3i\pi}{4}},e^{\frac{-7i\pi}{4}}$$

It works, doesn't it? Raise each of those to the power of 4 and you get $i$. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the exact expression that you're plugging into Wolfram?

Comment: (sqrt(sqrt(i). it recognizes it correctly

Comment: Is $e^{\frac{5\pi i}{4}}$ and $e^{-\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$ really different numbers? Same with the other two. Try writing your numbers with the argument in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: $\sqrt{\sqrt{i}}$ is single-valued (and takes value $e^{i\pi/8}$) under usual definition of square root, because we are taking a particular branch so that $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ is a single-valued function. If you are discussing the number of solutions of $z^4 = i$, then it has exactly 4 solution, all of which you have listed.

Comment: Thank You all, it's me being silly rather than anything as Winther suggested two roots are repeated. So the polynomial will have 4 roots but only two of them are distinct. That also explains why Wolfram only bother with listing two of them. Thanks for help

Comment: My comment was to your computation (and not to the problem in itself). There is one more error. As people have noted you have not found (all) the solutions to $z^4 = i$.

Comment: Ok, I solved the polynomial, it indeed gave me 4 distinct solutions, two of those being the roots of my equation. I confuse myself too often with those by not knowing what I am actually looking for.

Comment: Your reasoning to the effect that there should be four values for $\sqrt{\sqrt i}$ was exactly correct. There _are_ four values, and your explanation of why is correct. Your calculation of those values was wrong, missed two.

Comment: You made an error in the calculations again. $(1/4)/2\ne1/4$.

Comment: The question might be recast as "How many fourth roots does $i$ have?$ Iterating the square root may, or may not, give the same answer depending about choices of branches etc. The analysis of what the answer might, or should, be is all very well. The cautionary tale is that where there is ambiguity of definition, take care, especially when using aids to calculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your list of four solutions only has two - as has been pointed out you listed two of them twice. (In the original post, anyway...) But there are four roots.

First, $i=e^{i\pi/2}=e^{i5\pi/2}$ leads gives two values for $\sqrt i$, namely $e^{i\pi/4}$ and $e^{i5\pi/4}$. Each of these has two square roots: Since $e^{i\pi/4}=e^{i9\pi/4}$ it has the two square roots $e^{i\pi/8}$ and $e^{i9\pi/8}$. Similarly $e^{i5\pi/4}=e^{i13\pi/4}$ has the two square roots $e^{i5\pi/8}$ and $e^{i13\pi/8}$. For a total of four values of $\sqrt{\sqrt i}$, namely $$e^{i\pi/8},e^{i5\pi/8},e^{i9\pi/8},e^{i13\pi/8}.$$

**NOTE** Others have suggested that although a complex number has two square roots, the notation $\sqrt z$ refers to only one of them. I think it's wrong to put it that way; that notation refers to only one of them *if* we have clearly stated in advance which "branch" we're referring to. But Wolfram is wrong in any case. By my lights, $i$ has two square roots, each of which has two square roots, for a total of four as above. But *if* we are saying that the notation $\sqrt z$ refers to *one* square root, then Wolfram should say there's only *one* value for $\sqrt{\sqrt i}$, namely the one square root of the one square root.

I think four is the right number. With that convention there's only *one*; there's no sensible way to give exactly two values, as WA does. You can't believe everything they tell you.

Comment: Thank You, That cleared everything. I wouldn't start with expressing i as two "different" exponential. I guess maybe such reasoning will come with experience. :)

Comment: So a complex number has four fourth roots. You can find the fourth roots of $i$ by writing $i$ as an exponential in four different ways. There are actually _infinitely many_ ways to write $i$ as an exponential, but it happens they lead to only four fourth roots. So what you should do next is find all the infinitely many values of $i^i$, obtained from the infinite list of ways to wrrite $i=e^{it}$.

Comment: I must disagree with this. The square root function is perfectly well defined as a function. Have a look at my answer if you'd like to understand why Alpha responds the way that it does.

Comment: @MarkMcClure The _principal branch of the square root_ is what's perfectly well defined as a function. You can say that's "the square root" if you want but that's in no way a standard definition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich As I said in my response to this same comment on my answer, the question concerns WolframAlpha's response, which is built on top of Mathematica's `Sqrt` function which is well known to return the principal square root.

Answer (score 2):

Trick is to introduce an unknown, $z$. Write $z=\sqrt{ \sqrt{i}}$. We want to know how many values are possible for $z$. Squaring we get $z^2=\surd i$. Again squaring we  get $z^4-i=0$. This is a polynomial of degree 4 over the complex  numbers. So it has 4 roots. Taking the derivative shows that the roots are distinct.

SO we have 4 distinct values for the number.

EDIT (to clarify the doubts raised by SHailesh and Piquito in the comments):

For a  polynomial $f(z)$ to have $\alpha$ as repeated root means it is of the form $(z-\alpha)^2 g(z)$ for some other polynomial $g(z)$.Calculating derivative of $f(z)$ using product rule makes it clear that $\alpha$ will also be a root of the derivative $f'(z)$; and converse is also true.

@Piquito: Fundamental theorem of algebra states that the number of roots is equal to the degree of the polynomial only when we count them with multiplicity  and include    complex roots, real irrational roots.

Comment: I did not understand taking the derivative part. Could you elaboratte ?

Comment: Why over $\mathbb C$ and not over $\mathbb Q$ so you have eight values?

Comment: @Shailesh and Piquito: My answer above  has been edited and revised.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the other answers, there are four complex numbers $z$ with the property that $z^4=i$. If you would like to understand the behavior exhibited by WolframAlpha, however, you should consider the fact that its square root function is (in fact) a *function* built on top of Mathematica's `Sqrt` command. It returns exactly one number, namely 
$$\sqrt{r e^{i\theta}} = \sqrt{r} e^{i\theta/2},$$
when $r\geq0$ and $-\pi<\theta\leq\pi.$
As a result, $\sqrt{\sqrt{i}}$ is uniquely determined to be
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{i}} = \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \approx 0.92388 + 0.382683 i.$$
That is exactly what Wolfram Alpha has told you in the first couple of pods.

When you say that Alpha says there are two roots, I assume that you are referring to the last couple of pods that refer to "all 2nd roots of $(-1)^{1/4}$".  First off, those pods would be considered secondary. They arise because WolframAlpha typically produces secondary pods containing related information in an effort to respond to the various things that a human user might have meant in their input.

The reason that there are two is because `sqrt(sqrt(i))` essentially parses as

```
sqrt(a complex number)
```

so you get the two roots of that complex number in the secondary pod. You would get the same result, if you type `sqrt((1+i)/sqrt(2))` because 
$$\sqrt{i} = (1+i)/\sqrt{2}.$$

Finally, if you want all four fourth roots of $i$, simply type

```
all fourth roots of i
```

You can get more information on how WolframAlpha deals with roots in [this blog post](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/04/26/get-real-with-wolframalpha-computing-roots/).

Comment: Most people would say that's not "the square root", rather it's the _principal branch_ of the square root.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Exactly - and that's what Mathematica's `Sqrt` function has returned since 1988.

Comment: So? Are you claiming that Mathematica is the universal authority on mathematical definitions? I'm not disputing that that's what the Mathematica Sqrt function returns - that doesn't make it The square root in _mathematics_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, I am not claiming that Mathematica is the universal authority. I am answering a question about the behavior of a particular software tool, however, so I think that a proper understanding of that behavior requires an understanding of the conventions employed by that software.

Comment: If you say so. It's not clear to me that the question is about the behavior of Mathematica, as opposed to about what the mathematical truth is. There are only two question marks in the original post - those questions appear to me to be questions about the validity of the OP's calculations.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The question is tagged `wolfram-alpha` and expresses clear confusion over the response provided by WolframAlpha. Whether that's the *main* subject matter of the question or not, it's clear that an answer providing insight into the behavior provided by that specific software is, at least, germane to the discussion. I've edited my answer to indicate that my intention is to address that specific aspect. Incidentally, I personally wrote the code that generates much of the Alpha output, so I think it's safe to say that I know what I'm talking about, at least, in this context.

Comment: I agree with everything you just said - given the clarification that you're talking about Sqrt and not sqrt, I find the post admirable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can write $i$ as $i=e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)}$ for any integer $k$.  Then, taking a square root, we see that

$$\sqrt{i}=e^{i(\pi/4+k\pi)} \tag 1$$

for any integer $k$.  Note that there are two distinct values of $\sqrt i$ in $(1)$; for $k=-1,0$, we have $\sqrt i = e^{-3i\pi/4}$ and $\sqrt i = e^{i\pi/4}, respectively.

Taking the square root of the right-hand side of $(1)$ gives

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{i}}=e^{i(\pi/8+k\pi/2)}$$

for which there are $4$ distinct values corresponding to $k=-2,-1,0,1$.  The solutions are $e^{-i7\pi/8}$, $ e^{-i3\pi/8}$, $e^{i\pi/8}$, and $e^{i5\pi/8}$